# Jquery Plugin/Widget for showing a floating pick list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'd like to create a jquery widget that attaches to a textbox and inserts an icon on the far right side.  If the textbox has focus, it would behave normally, but if the icon was clicked it would show a panel of values to choose from.

Before I create this myself I'd like to know if it already exists out there somewhere.  I've tried searching for "jquery pick list", "jquery panel", etc....but I haven't found anything.  Boltbus.com has a decent example for the input of their to/from locations.

[image: Screenshot from boltbus.com]

Comment: Making a custom menu appear on clicking an icon and copying the clicked item's value into a textbox is trivial, your example is not. The reason is that your example probably does a lot of CSS magic. Take a look at the source of the menu, I bet that there will be a ton of divs and anchors each with a CSS class, styles and absolute positioning. The jQuery part will consist of making a few elements appear, disappear and retrieval of text. If you can get the HTML/CSS structure up and running and post it back, I am sure you will get a lot of jQuery help in doing what you want to do.

Comment: Ok, so they seem to be using a custom control that generates divs as a super-styled <select> replacement...

Answer (score 0):

You want Q-tip maybe? http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/ or another tooltip type plugin